# Incremental loading and BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Im writing an incremental loading pipeline to load data from MySQL to BigQuery and using Google Cloud Datastore as a metadata repo.

My current pipeline is written this way:

```
PCollection<TableRow> tbRows = 
pipeline.apply("Read from MySQL",
        JdbcIO.<TableRow>read().withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
                .create("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", connectionConfig)
                .withUsername(username)
                .withPassword(password)
                .withQuery(query).withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                .withRowMapper(JdbcConverters.getResultSetToTableRow())))
    .setCoder(NullableCoder.of(TableRowJsonCoder.of()));

tbRows.apply("Write to BigQuery",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().withoutValidation()
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND).to(outputTable));

tbRows.apply("Getting timestamp column",
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                        .via((final TableRow row) -> (String) row.get(fieldName)))
                .setCoder(NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of())).apply("Max", Max.globally())
                .apply("Updating Datastore", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(final ProcessContext c) {
                        DatastoreConnector.udpate(table, c.element());
                    }
                }));
```

The problem I am facing is that when the BigQuery Write step fails the Datastore is still updated, is there any way to wait for BigQuery Write finish before updating the Datastore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this cannot be done in the same pipeline with `BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()` since it produces a terminal output (`PDone`). I have some suggestions though.

- I suspect BigQuery write failing is a rare occurrence. In this case can you delete corresponding Datastore data from a secondary job/process.
- Have you considered a CDC solution that is better suited for writing incremental change data. For example see the Dataflow template [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#datastream-to-bigquery).